# Does the stopping time sequence given by the hitting time of $n$ reduce any continuous local martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, local-martingales

I stumbled upon this, but it doesn't feel right. Is the following true?

Let $X$ be a cont. local martingale, $S_n= \inf \{ t | |X_t|\geq n \} $.
Then $X^{S_n}$ is a martingale for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

The reasoning being that $$\mathbb{E}[\sup_{0\leq s \leq t} |X^{S_n}_t|]\leq n<\infty \text{ for each $t\geq 0$}.$$

So is this true? One thing I could see going wrong is having $S_n{\uparrow} \infty $ not hold. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you intend your stopping time to be $S_n= \inf \{ t | \, |X_t|\geq n \} $

Comment: Yes exactly, going to edit it now! My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $Y_t = X_t^{S_n}$; then $Y_t$, being a stopped local martingale is a local martingale. It is, moreover, a bounded local martingale, which renders it into a true martingale. To see this, let $(\tau_k)$ be a localising sequence for $Y_t$ and note that for each $k$, $E(Y_{t \land \tau_k} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_s) = Y_{s \land \tau_k}$. Since $Y$ is bounded, we may use dominated convergence to get:

$$Y_s = \lim_{k\to \infty} Y_{s \land \tau_k} = \lim_{k\to \infty} E(Y_{t \land \tau_k} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_s) = E(Y_{t} \, | \, \mathcal{F}_s)$$

as desired.

Comment: Very clear! Thank you very much! May I ask then, is there a reason for defining local martingales by saying "there is a localizing sequence which makes it a martingale" instead of just saying "if the sequence of hitting times of $n$ makes it a martingale"?

Comment: @uniform_on_compacts I suspect one could construct a local martingale which is not localised by the first hitting times of level $n$, but I can't think of one now. I think it's worth posting it as another MSE question.

Comment: Your answer above proves that there is no such *continuous* local martingale, so maybe this can occur when it is not continuous.